# Vue.js todo list with calendar

Tags: vue.js, calendar

I want to make a todo list in vue.js with calendar.

So, generally, I need a calendar and depending on the chosen date, the todolist is showing. This app must have a basic CRUD functionality, so, basically, it's a todo app with the calendar and local storage.

Can anyone drop me some link of the similar apps? They don't have to be the same, but I have a problem with calendar's connection to the todo list.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Vuetify.js](https://vuetifyjs.com/). It provides a number of components that works with vue.js out of the box. You can find the calendar components [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars).

I suggest you create a vue landing page that contains your calendar. Then mock out your store in the component data to provide dummy data to your calendar. Then hook up your data to a vue (vuex) store. See [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html).

You can read from your store or you can take it a step further and hook up your store to a database or local storage.